# Printing invoices from web application using dot matrix printer

Tags: php, html, web, printing

We have a php application with the invoice page designed in HTML and when printed the page has format and clarity issues, e.g. Font is not clearly visible and the table format is jumbled.

We tried changing fonts, but that didn't help. I would appreciate any pointers to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I remember, dot matrix prints how it prints. So pick a font that suits what the printer is going to print on the web page.

Comment: consider using a simplified print-only CSS file (you can set it print-only using media queries, without affecting the on-screen layout) that can specify a font and layout that the printer can handle better.